# How to calculate distance between lat/long in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-maps

In a c# winform application I've a latitude/longitude List. I can to calculate in sql server (2005) query but I dont know if I can do this in c#.

```
SELECT LAT, LONG, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( LAT ) ) * cos( radians( LONG ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM Table ORDER BY distance
```

Using This query in sql server I can order a list of latitude and longitude. 
But, in c# I've lat/long in this list:

```
var latLon = new List<LatLonClass>();
```

Using this list, How can I do same query in my List?
Thanks!

Comment: You can looking into the Math class to get what you need, I think.

Comment: Using LINQ would help you greatly here. Please add the definition of the `LatLonClass` to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how accurate results you need. Our earth isn't sphere, it is ellipsoid (one can say radius is between 6378137m and 6356752m) . Thats why for accurate result you need to know math on very adwanced level. If you need more precision than 0.3% I suggest you use Charles Karney's GeographicLib - http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/NET/

If precision at 0.3% level is enough for you use @Mark code.

Answer (score 3):

Just see the [`System.Device.Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

```
var coord1 = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lon1);
var coord2 = new GeoCoordinate(lat2, lon2);

var dist = coord1.GetDistanceTo(coord2);
```

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx

Now, to calculate  distances of a list of cordinates to a single point

```
List<GeoCoordinate> coordinates = ......;
GeoCoordinate point = ......;

var distances = coordinates.Select(c => c.GetDistanceTo(point))
                           .OrderBy()
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet from the Haversine formula, found (`https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/`). Looks like it has what you need.

```
public double HaversineDistance(LatLng pos1, LatLng pos2, DistanceUnit unit)
{
    double R = (unit == DistanceUnit.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;
    var lat = (pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude).ToRadians();
    var lng = (pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude).ToRadians();
    var h1 = Math.Sin(lat / 2) * Math.Sin(lat / 2) +
                  Math.Cos(pos1.Latitude.ToRadians()) * Math.Cos(pos2.Latitude.ToRadians()) *
                  Math.Sin(lng / 2) * Math.Sin(lng / 2);
    var h2 = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(h1)));
    return R * h2;
}
```